# Delete chars from string C

Tags: c, string, function

So i start learning C from a book, and one of the exercises was to create a function that will take 2 string and delete from the first string the characters in the second string.

We stile didn't learn about pointer, so i guess this is possible without them,
but when i try to run my code its crush.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char squis(char string[], char sub[])
{
    int i, c;
    char ret_string[strlen(string)];
    int map[strlen(string)];
    for(i=0; i<= strlen(string);i++)
        map[i] = -1;
    for(i=0; i<= strlen(sub);i++)
    {
        while(string[c]!='\0')
        {
            if (string[c]==sub[i])
                map[c] = c;
            c++;
        }
        c=0;
    }
    for(i=0; i<= strlen(string);i++)
    {
        if (map[i]==-1)
            ret_string[c++] = string[i];
    }
    ret_string[c] ='\0';
    return ret_string[0];
}

int main()
{
    char string[] = "string";
    char remove[] = "sasas";
    printf("%s",squis(string,remove));
    return 0;
}
```

I stile newbie in C, so I think the problem lay on my lack of understanding in the way that C work.

Thanks a lot for help :-)

Update: its seem the problem laying in the return in the end of the function.
The function seems to work well when when i print `ret_string` inside the function(except one bug that make the function ignore the first char in the sub string, but i will deal with it later), but when i try to return the array to print it in the main function its fail.

There is specific rules for returning array in C?

Comment: Don't forget space for the terminating `'\0'` in your strings.

Comment: On top of my head - `i<= strlen(string)` examine this carefully..check how indexing is done in C

Comment: Try not to put too many commands into one line, use temporay variables, learn to use as debuffer and use it to trace your code step by step inspecting all relevant variables, to discover what really happends.

Comment: Look at what your `squis` routine *returns* -- it's not a string, even though you are *telling* your program it is one (by requesting `%s` in `printf`).

Comment: Also `"%s"` expects a pointer to `char` that is `char*` or an array of `char`, which would decay to a pointer if passed to `printf()`) and not a `char` itself.

Comment: when i change it to `return ret_string;` i get `- function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 - return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by 
  default]`. I dont understand what its mean

Comment: Ok, I try to debug my code like you suggest, i update the main topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an obvious problem:

```
int map[strlen(string)];
for(i=0; i<= strlen(string);i++)
    map[i] = -1;
```

You create an array of `strlen(string)` characters, and then you initialize `strlen(string) + 1` characters in the array. Writing out of bounds of an array leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), where anything could happen.

Change the loop condition to less-than `<`. You should probably do it in all your loops.

You have a similar problem with `ret_string`, which will be the string you return. It's going to be at most `strlen(string)` characters, but then you need to add one character for the string terminator so the array needs to be `strlen(string) + 1` long.

Then you have the problem that the `squis` function only return *a single character* but in your `printf` call you treat this single character as a string. This should make your compiler scream a warning at you. If you fix this by simply returning `ret_string` you will have another case of *undefined behavior*, as you then return a pointer to a local variable, which goes out of scope when the function exits, so the returned pointer is no longer valid. And if you decide to allocate `ret_string` on the heap, with the current call you have a memory leak as then the pointer is not saved so you can free the allocated memory.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with strlen() .`string[] = "string";` so `strlen(string))= 6`. if i will create `string2[6]` 0-5 will hold the word `string` and 6 will use for `\0`, am i wrong?

Comment: @OrHalimi Yes, `strlen(string)` will return `6`, but you have an array of ***`7`*** characters including the terminator. And if you create an array of six characters to hold seven characters, well, I hope you can see the problem there.

Comment: ho, I see. And I need to define the array with maloc? then my problems will over?

Comment: @OrHalimi For `ret_string` you need to allocate off the heap yes, and it will solve some of your problems.